# need help sorting the data off a tsv in a C# console program.

Tags: c#, sorting, console, csv

I am trying to sort the data using the 3rd column from a tab separated txt file. Tried a couple of ways, not sure how I sort it using the 3rd column. have sorted it using the first for now. Also I need to remove duplicates from the 3rd column(Case sensitiver i.e. riVEr is different than River) Here is my code so far. will mark as an answer as soon as I get progress. Thanks ;)

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"d:\instance_test.txt");
//Dictionary<String, Int32> EAR_appcode = new Dictionary<String, Int32>();
//Console.WriteLine();
//Console.ReadLine();
//// Display the file contents by using a foreach loop.
//System.Console.WriteLine("Contents of WriteLines2.txt = ");
//foreach (string line in lines)
//{
//    // Use a tab to indent each line of the file.
//    Console.WriteLine("\t" + line.Substring(4));
//    Console.ReadLine();
//}
var no = lines;

var orderedScores = lines.OrderBy(x => x.Split(' ')[0]);
//string result = Regex.Split(no, @"[,\t ]+");
foreach (var score in orderedScores)
{
    string replacement = Regex.Replace(score, @"\t|\n|\r", "           ");
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("myCol", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("myCol2", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("EAR_appcode", typeof(string));
    table.Rows.Add(11, "abc11");
    table.Rows.Add(13, "abc13");
    table.Rows.Add(12, "abc12");
    Console.WriteLine(replacement) ;
    Console.ReadLine();

}
// Keep the console window open in debug mode.
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
System.Console.ReadKey();

}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer but I am still facing problems. The data is being shown incorrectly and all of my column headings went down to 3rd rows, haha.

Comment: the question is still open, answers appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my sample data:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
zxcv    789 14:02
asdf    123 12:00
qwer    456 13:01
asdf    123 12:00
```

I used this LINQ statement to:

1. Create a range of indexes from "start" to "lines.Length - 1"
2. Split by '\t'
3. Dump each column into an anonymous type
4. Group by string that is a combination of all columns
5. Select only the first item for each group
6. Sort by column 3

   ```
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("Tab.txt");
       int start = 1; // set to zero, if no header

       var records = (from i in Enumerable.Range(start, lines.Length - 1)
                      let pieces = lines[i].Split('\t')
                      select new { Col1 = pieces[0], Col2 = pieces[1], Col3 = pieces[2] })
                      .GroupBy(c => c.Col1 + c.Col2 + c.Col3)
                      .Select(gr => gr.First())
                      .OrderBy(c => c.Col3);

       foreach (var r in records)
           Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}", r.Col1, r.Col2, r.Col3);

       Console.WriteLine();
       Console.WriteLine("Done");
       Console.ReadLine();
   }
   ```

Of course, you can add parsing/conversion code in the last line of the LINQ statement to order by int or DateTime.

And I tested it ...

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer but I am still facing problems. The data is being shown incorrectly and all of my column headings went down to 3rd rows, haha.

Comment: I get the lines separately from the LINQ. define how many lines I need to skip ("start"). Enumerable.Range() is effectively creating a "for" loop.

Comment: maybe, it sorted the entire thing, thinking of my column header as a part of the data. makes sense brother

Comment: got it to work. just displaying 3 rows beneath the heading, any ideas on how to get the rest to show up. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
// read lines somehow
// ...
// create a list
var list = new List<Tuple<string, string, string>>();
foreach(string line in lines)
{
    var split = line.Split('\x9');
    list.Add(new Tuple(split[0], split[1], split[2]));
}
// sort
list = list.OrderBy(x => x.Item3);
// remove duplicates
for(int i = 1; i < list.Count; i++)
    if(list[i].Item3 == list[i-1].Item3)
        list.RemoveAt(i);
```

I believe all above can be done with just one linq expression, but I am very bad in it. Have to steal `OrderBy` part from you anyway ^^.

If you don't have .Net Framework 4.0, then substitute [`Tuple`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) with non-generic version (declare list as `List<Tuple>`):

```
class Tuple
{
    public string Item1;
    public string Item2;
    public string Item3;
    public Tuple(string i1, string i2, string i3)
    {
        Item1 = i1;
        Item2 = i2;
        Item3 = i3;
    }
}
```

Comment: your answer is giving out an error, what assembly reference do i need to use tuple? tried all the user System. references.

Comment: thanks, the place I work uses 3.5, i'll see into it, appreciate the help!

Comment: msdn says, I cannot use Tuple, let me know if you have any other way. thanks man